# Cannot find symbol in intellij Idea

Tags: java

Car.java file

```
public class Car {
    String model;
    int year;
    int price;
    String color;

    public Car(String model, int year, int price, String color) {
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", year=" + year +
                ", price=" + price +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

CarManager.java file

```
public class CarManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car bmw = new Car("m5", 2020, 50000, "black");
        Car rr = new Car("sport", 2019, 70000, "white");

        System.out.println(bmw);
        System.out.println(rr);
    }
}
```

Error:

> ```
> error: compilation failed
>
> CarManager.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
>         Car bmw = new Car("m5", 2020, 50000, "black");
>         ^
>   symbol:   class Car
>   location: class CarManager
> CarManager.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
>         Car bmw = new Car("m5", 2020, 50000, "black");
>                       ^
>   symbol:   class Car
>   location: class CarManager
> CarManager.java:8: error: cannot find symbol.
>
> Error cannot find symbol.
> ```

What do you think is possible can the problem be from IDEA ?

Comment: Is the Car class imported in the CarManager class?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible options here to make this code work.

1. Place both Car.java & CarManager.java in the same package.

OR

2. import class Car in CarManager.java